# How many of these numbers are written in scientific notation? $\sqrt7\times10^{-20}$, $5.3\times2^{10}$, $(\frac13)^{-1}\times10^{15}$

Tags: scientific-notation

> How many numbers are written in scientific notation?
>
> - $\sqrt7\times10^{-20}$
> - $5.3\times2^{10}$
> - $(\frac13)^{-1}\times10^{15}$
>
> $1)\text{zero}\qquad\qquad2)1\qquad\qquad3)2\qquad\qquad4)3$

We know that in base $10$ the scientific notation of a number is in the form $c\times10^n$ where $c$ is a number between $1$ and $10$ (not including $10$) and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence the second number ($5.3\times2^{10}$) is excluded. the third number is the same as $3\times10^{15}$ and I think it is written in scientific notation but for the first one I have doubts because although $\sqrt7\in[1,10)$ but haven't' seen this form of number as a scientific notation before.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you have the notion of "*scientific notation*" defined, and there is some leeway with how that is done.  It is common to require the number $c$ to be written in decimal format with no repeated trailing nines as well as to require $1\leq |c|<10$ so as to have only one valid representation for each number possible in which case I would say none of them are in (*normalized*) scientific notation... but I could see an argument that the other two should be considered to be as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the help. I agree,  It seems the question isn't  posed very well.